# Why can't "happy" be used everywhere where "sad" can be used?

Tags: meaning

Why can I say "that story had a happy ending"?  But I cannot say "that story was happy"?  On the other hand, I can say "that story had a sad ending" and I could say "that story was sad"?

Comment: Probably cause "happy" also means "lucky" or "fortunate", and a lucky story doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You could say "That story made me happy", or "made me sad".

Comment: Your second example is awkward, because the story itself is not sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as we can't find two words in English that are synonymous across their whole range of senses, and would also expect to find situations where one may be used and the other, though it carries the same sense, for some reason, may not be, we shouldn't expect words to be antonymous across their whole range of senses, and we shouldn't expect them to have identical distributions.

Answer (score 2):

You can say “that story was happy”. There is no ambiguity because a story cannot feel emotion, so it must be causing that emotion. English overloads emoting with emotion-causing. The same is true for “a happy ending”: we don’t mean that the ending of the story was actually feeling happiness itself.

There are, however, some adjectives that can only be used in attributive or predicative position. For example:

> I ate the entire cake.
> *The cake was entire.
>
> The man is awake.
> *He is an awake man.

Comment: This is all true, but I don't see that it directly answers OP's specific question. There are far more written instances of *sad story* than *happy story*, and it's the same with *story was sad/happy*. But I can't see any reason to suppose that's because there really are more "sadness-inducing" stories than "happiness-inducing" ones, or that for some reason we tend to write about the sad ones more often. So it seems to me the "lop-sidedness" of *sad/happy* must be more a matter of established idiomatic preference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If the question is “why can’t we?” then the answer is “but we can”. If the question is “why don’t we?” then it’s just as you said, an arbitrary phenomenon somewhere along the spectrum of set phrases and stormy petrels.

Comment: Earlier today it took me several minutes to come up with *stormy petrels* in a comment. I knew what I was looking for, having come across it somewhen in the last 2-3 years - but I couldn't remember the actual term, and my Google-fu deserted me when it came to suitable search terms. Not least because I couldn't think of *any* specific examples, let alone the archetypal one. Indeed, it does seem that idiomatically speaking, *stories that are happy* are about as rare as hen's teeth (and non-stormy petrels! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Here, have [an okay poem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRlpRFs2L30) with a bunch of them.

Comment: Nice one! I especially like the "definitive" ending. It may not be high poetry, but it's an engaging bit of non-trivial doggerel, and that finale is as satisfying as an [After Eight Mint dinner mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_Eight) (the link is just in case you don't have such things in the US! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question. I agree with you that, informally (in US english), one might say "This story is sad" but not "This story is happy."

Google n-grams provides evidence for this idea [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=story+is+happy%2Cstory+is+sad&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstory%20is%20happy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstory%20is%20sad%3B%2Cc0) and [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happy%20story,%20sad%20story&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,happy%20story;,c0;.t1;,sad%20story;,c0).

I'm only speculating as to the reason for this. I'd say it's because even though when we say "This is a sad book" as in "This book made me sad", what we really mean is "This story had elements that evoked sadness." We're describing the book's effect on us rather than the book itself. It's easy to imagine a story causing emotions of surprise, excitement, interest, sadness. That's why I think it sounds natural to say a story is surprising, exciting, interesting, sad, or even uplifting. On the other hand, most stories will not create an emotion we'd simply call "happiness.", although that's certainly possible.

"Happy ending", I think, is just an opposite to "sad ending." If I read a story where everything ends up OK, I'd call it a "happy ending" even if I was intensely bored by it and didn't care about any of the characters. Similarly, if someone dies or something bad happens, I'd say it's a "sad ending" even if I don't care. I think sad here means a different concept than if a story is sad, which is why "happy ending" is OK but "story is happy" is not.

Comment: Weird. We have basically the same arguments for opposite conclusions.